# Cron job syntax on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I am trying to schedule a job to run "every 15 minutes on weekdays only" using the Google App Engine cron scheduler (for Java apps).
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html#The_Schedule_Format

Does any know what the correct syntax is? I have tried using the xml below, but find that it runs on all days not just the weekdays listed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/finance/collect</url>
    <description>Fetch data every 15 minutes</description>
    <schedule>every 15 minutes monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation, once you specify days you can only specify a single absolute time for the task to run.

I suggest you check the day of week in your job and do nothing if it is not a weekday.

Answer (score 1):

How to config a task to run every 5 minutes between 9:00am~20:00pm, 
but every 10 minutes in other time of the day.

Comment: Leon, you can do it by combining two tasks:

First one:

    `every 5 minutes from 09:00 to 20:00`

Second one:

    `every 10 minutes from 20:00 to 09:00`

Answer (score 0):

According to your link it appears the only difference is the fact that you have a space in the schedule tag between the selectors and this example does not:

```
2nd,third mon,wed,thu of march 17:00
```